# Hide paper-header-panel by default

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm playing around with Polymer project and want to create a layout similar to Google Play Music (https://play.google.com/music).

How can I hide the drawer by default and display the icon? Basically the small screen behavior of paper-drawer-panel should be forced.
How can I create a app toolbar similar to Play Music?

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

        <paper-drawer-panel responsiveWidth="9999px">

            <paper-header-panel drawer>
                <paper-toolbar>
                    <div>Application</div>
                </paper-toolbar>
                <div>Drawer content...</div>
            </paper-header-panel>

            <paper-header-panel main>
                <paper-toolbar>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                    <div>Title</div>
                </paper-toolbar>
                <div>Main content...</div>
            </paper-header-panel>

        </paper-drawer-panel>

    </template>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Erm... How about just `force-narrow`?

```
<paper-header-panel force-narrow>
  ...
</paper-header-panel>
```

as described in "paper-header-panel.html":

```
    /**
     * If true, ignore `responsiveWidth` setting and force the narrow layout.
     */
    forceNarrow: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false
    },
```

Comment: That worked too, thank you. The documentation is wrong, it says that attribute should be forceNarrow.

Comment: Sure thing. But to be fair, the documentation, while confusing maybe, is not exactly wrong. HTML attributes are not case-sensitive, so `camelCase` is serialized into `dash-case`.  Refer to: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-deserialization

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! The documentation is pretty useless when such basics like attributes are not correct.

```
<paper-drawer-panel responsive-width="10000px">
```